# Google Sheets - Return X rows based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have a list of names:

[image]

And I have another list for how many rows of each name I want to see:

[image]

How do I create a formula that outputs the following (notice how I want to take the first X of each first + last name grouping):

[image]

Here is the link to the Google sheets if you'd like to write it out: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hBmQmC3IKyJwnPpx_xCf1WXlATEGbJpKwo8nlcB5So/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added solution to your [tab here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hBmQmC3IKyJwnPpx_xCf1WXlATEGbJpKwo8nlcB5So/edit#gid=1059990012)

`=QUERY(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,INDEX(XLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,E:E&F:F,G:G,)),LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,dx,IF(ax="",,IF(ax<=dx,{ax,bx,cx},)))),"Select * Where Col2!=''")`

-

[image]